# Tire : Eager loading associations from multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, include, tire

I am using elasticsearch for querying in my application. Lets say there are 2 models

```
Class Topic
   has_many :posts
```

and

```
Class Article
  has_many :comments
```

I want to do a combined search on both these models and my query looks like:

```
Tire.search [Article, Topic], {:load => {:include => [:posts, :comments]}} do |search|
...
end
```

This is where I encounter a problem. I get the

```
Association named comments not found
```

error. I think this is because Topic model doesn't have the association comments and I think the same thing will happen for posts with the Article model.

Is there anyway to solve this problem? I was thinking maybe something like

```
:include => ['topic.posts', 'article.comments']
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved a similar issue, based on some guidance I found on [this post](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4419367). That answer says to try this:

```
 Tire.search [Article, Topic], {:load => { Article =>{ :include => :comments}, 
                                           Topic => { :include => :posts }
                                         } }  do |search|
```

In my case, I needed a to load nested associations, where I had a two-deep hierarchy that I wanted Tire to eagerly load. So I adapted that solution to my case:

```
Tire.search 'articles', {:load => { :include => [:contributors, 
                                                 :books => [:authors]] } } do
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used the same. Sorry for not posting the answer. And FYI, this is what i referred to: https://github.com/karmi/retire/issues/762